# Wordpress array to show post from certain category and show post excerpt and feature ing

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

Hi all looking for a Wordpress help. I need to place a simple query/array to display posts from a certain cat e.g "News' that will include the posts featured image.

Can anyone please help?

Gary

Comment: Just a simple...

<?php query_posts('cat=8&showposts=4'); ?>

Comment: But I want to include the post feature img as the thumb not sure how to phrase the PHP..

Comment: Please don't add unrelated new questions to an existing one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query('category_name=News&posts_per_page=4');
    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    the_excerpt(); // or the_content(); for full post content
    endwhile;endif;
?>
```

Comment: it works beautifully. but how would I keep it so that each post adds pagenation to the slider, as at current there is no slide action just a simple list of the posts.

Comment: Not sure what did you mean by slider.

Comment: sorry. Please see http://garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/ if you look at where it says "latest news" I've input a simple html content slider. That I'd like once the site is into WP to scroll/slide through 5 latest news posts. Does this make sense?

Comment: For that you need to use javascript (maybe jQuery plugin).

Comment: I know, I have one. not sure how to ingrate it into wordpress. For example the above code displays all the posts in cat "news" but I'm not sure how to configure the php so the slider markup stays in tact.

Comment: How did you integrated the one above ?

Comment: Try this `$('#slider2').tinycarousel({ pager: true, interval: true  });` inside your `<head>$(document).ready(function(){...})</head>`, i saw there is already you have it but without `interval: true`, may be this will do the work.

Comment: I have changed the ready function to interval true. The code is working, but I'm implementing it wrong as it just displays a list of the posts within the cat "news" instead of each post being a slide. please see -> http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/screenshot_01.jpg to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: If you want to show each post then you should remove the `category_name=News&` from the `WP_Query`.

Comment: You misunderstand. I want each post from the cat "news" to be a slide in the slider. so the newest post would be the first slide, the second post would be the second slide etc ...

Comment: I'm really confused now. please post another question with more details mentioning javascript/jQuery and try to post some code and also a fiddle (if possible). This thread should be closed/accepted. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134898/transfering-work-jqery-slider-from-html-to-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query_posts(). Its intention is to modify the default Wordpress Loop, and should not be used for general queries. Use [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [Get Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead.

Here's some documentation on [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

Here's a small example based on what you showed me that might work. Notice that 'showposts' has been changed to 'posts_per_page', as 'showposts' was deprecated as of version 2.1:

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>8, 'posts_per_page'=>4));
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    the_excerpt();
    if(has_post_thumbnail())
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the example you gave me, this should get you started:

```
<div id="slider2">
<div class="viewport">
    <?php
    $q = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>8, 'posts_per_page'=>4));
    if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="newsPost">
        <div class="news-date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
        <div class="newstitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="news-des"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
        <div class="newsimg"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More...</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>   
</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thankyou so much...

in my site all the news posts will be displayed on the homepage in a mini slider. 

can I split the above code up. For example 

'<div class="news-des"<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>8, 'posts_per_page'=>4));
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    the_excerpt(); (someting to close)</div>' - for the post excerpt, and then somthing like this for the thumb/feature img

<div class="newsimg"> if(has_post_thumbnail())
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
endwhile;endif;
?></div>

Comment: Absolutely, something like that can be done. But I would personally keep your opening and closing tags for each corresponding post within the loop. You can also have a "wrapper" div open right before the loop and close immediately after as well, to contain all of your post divs.

Comment: arh ok. This is my HTML to my slider with dummy content.

Comment: Update your question with your example. I can update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: This is a snippet from my html showing the first slide of my mini slider could you advise where to put the appropriate PHP?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gya2u/

my homepage design -> http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/student-i-home-960px.jpg

Comment: a live WIP HTML version of site -> http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/index.html