# wordpress Query posts from specific category with post thumbnail and excerpt

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress array to show post from certain category and show post excerpt and feature ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133784/wordpress-array-to-show-post-from-certain-category-and-show-post-excerpt-and-fea)

Hi all in the process of coding up a WP theme. I have a slider on the homepage to display the latest posts from the "news' category. I've worked out how to display posts in the slider from the cat, but I don't know how to include the posts feature image and except. Can someone please advise.

this is my work in progress WP site. it's the "Latest News" slider.

http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i-wp/

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

you can add the featured image by including this piece of code inside your loop in the place you want your image to appear:

```php
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php endif; ?>
```

the exerpt you can add by replacing `the_content()` function with `the_exerpt()`.

lets say you have this piece of code inside your loop:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

you will replace it with this:

```
<?php the_exerpt(); ?>
```

there is a lot more to this then just adding and replacing, but I think that could get you started.

Hope this helps =].

**You are suposed to put everything inside the loop.**

Here is a full loop with the title, the thumnail and the content to use on your section...

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=news&posts_per_page=1');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<h2 id="yourTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div id="yourImage">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
</div>
<p id="yourContent"><?php the_exerpt(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Here we are telling the query to show your news category post and to show only 1 post `('category_name=news&posts_per_page=1')`

Comment: I've got this at the moment, I know it does not work, but can you see what I'm trying to do?

`
       <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </a>
 <?php endif; 
                            
                       
// The Query
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
// The Loop

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
 echo '<li>';
 the_title();
 echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>`

Comment: I'll extend on the answer... hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou.. the php causes errors tho. arh man